# Sizes in bibliography files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, amsart, amsrefs

I have a file using amsart and accessing an external .bib file.

I would like to generate a separate file of just the references appearing in my file. But I would like the entries in this file to appear in the same size and style as in any other amsart document, as though they were enumerated within an enumerate environment. (Amsrefs or plain bibtex renders bibliography entries smaller than regular text in amsart files.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can add a MWE of what you have got so far. Just to clarify: In your "main document" (let's call it that) you want references but no bibliography, and then you want to create another document containing only the bibliography of the main file?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Yes, that's exactly right, @moewe.

Comment: Aha.  Then you can use `bibtool` to extract a document-specific bibliography if you have a master `bib` file that contains more references than are in the article.  And then use that extracted `bib` file in the bibliography document: a `\nocite{*}` will put everything in a bibliography without any references showing up.  if the `bib` file already only contains the article references, then skip the `bibtool` step.  (I leave the details of the citations-without-bibliography to others since I don't use `amsart`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to change the size of the type used in an `amsart` bibliography to the "normal" text size,

- `\renewcommand{\bibliofont}{\normalfont\normalsize}` if using `bibtex`, or
- `\renewcommand{\biblistfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}` if using `amsrefs`.

i haven't time just now to explore the other part of your request, namely suppressing
output of the bibliography itself while honoring all `\cite`s.

Comment: This is perfect. Such a simple fix. The other parts are less important, though if you or someone else gets to them, it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @Skeptic The second part of your original question is quite unrelated to the one that barbara solved. Therefore I suggest that you remove that part from this question and re-post it as a new question, with a proper MWE of course ;)